# NoSQL for Asp.Net my experience with NoRM and MongoDB

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, norm, nosql

I develop in the last days a web page (http://www.srtbox.com/) for testing my architecture, more info [here](http://www.ranu.com.ar/2011/06/httpwwwsrtboxcom-nice-home-page-project.html).  With NoRM, MongoLab or MongoHQ for DB hosting. And I having a a lot of errors with NoRM. All with the Norm.BSON.BsonDeserializer class. I could fix one, but now im getting some errors in the connection. Error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count)
> at Norm.BSON.BsonDeserializer.Deserialize[T](BinaryReader stream, Int32 length)

The truth is that this NoRM driver seems really unstable... The official driver does not offer Linq support and I did not find one example with a POCO object.  Some one have a good experience with and NoSQL database and asp.net?? Scalable like MongoDB? RavenDB seems a nice option, but MongoDB have more success stories, of course without .Net .

So the big question is: Which NoSQL Scalable DB will you recommend for ASP.Net? Do you have any success story?

PD: I will be thankful if you visit my site: (http://www.srtbox.com/) for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a network error, not a problem with the driver. If the database isn't local you will see that if you have a bad connection or didn't set up the firewall right - not much you can do differently in code to change it. Trying to keep a single connection open for too long can also cause connection errors.

Most of the NoSQL databases available work well with .NET so you can choose based on functional requirements rather than .NET compatibility. However, you shouldn't expect it to work just like SQL or have that many examples - most of them are used primarily on other platforms and since they all have different ways of running queries, LINQ isn't always a good fit anyway.

Also, what do you mean by POCO? The serialization attributes can make the classes look complicated, but they are just regular objects, not the lazy loaded self updating objects you get from a typical ORM.

Comment: thanks for your question about POCO. Since that I have investigate more the offcial driver and its true its support POCO objects. I will try it.